# How to do a exact word replacment in a string using PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

I am using numbers as variable in a string to construct logic.

Here are example of the string that I have

```
(1 AND 2)
2  AND   1
(1 AND 2) OR  (3 AND 4)
1 AND (2  OR  3)
```

Then I have an array that looks like this

```
 $this->clause = array(
          '1' => (object) array('fieldId' => 'id',
                                'value' => 1),

          '2' => (object) array('fieldId' => 'cost',
                                'value' => 132),

          '3' => (object) array('fieldId' => 'name',
                                'value' => "Jay's LLC"),

          '4' => (object) array('fieldId' => 'first',
                                'value' => "Mike"),
        );
```

I am trying to replace the values in the string (1, 2, 3, and 4) with the corresponding values in the array.

Here how my strings will need to look like once done

first example "since the logic string does not contain the clause 3 and 4 then both will be added using 'AND' logic at the end of the string"

```
(1 AND 2) becomes
( id = '1' AND cost = '132' ) AND name = 'Jay\'s LLC' AND first = 'Mike'
```

Second example "since the logic string does not contain the clause 3 and 4 then both will be added using 'AND' logic at the end of the string"

```
    2  AND   1 becomes
    cost = '132' AND id = '1' AND name = 'Jay\'s LLC' AND first = 'Mike'
```

Third example "since the logic string does not contain the clause 4 then it will be added using 'AND' logic at the end of the string"

```
(1 AND 2) OR  (3 AND 4) becomes
( id = '1' AND cost = '132' ) OR (name = 'Jay\'s LLC')
```

Last example

```
1 AND (2  OR  3) AND 4 becomes
id = '1' (cost = '132' OR name = 'Jay\'s LLC') AND first = 'Mike'
```

Here is what I have tried

```
private function getAllWhereClauseStatements()
{
    $query = '';
    $totalClause = count($this->clause);

    if( $totalClause > 0 ){

        $query .= 'WHERE ';

        if( !empty($this->clauseLogic) ){
            $logic = '';
            $tmpLogic = $this->clauseLogic;
            foreach($this->clause as $key => $cl){
                $tmpLogic .= preg_replace('/\b'.$key.'\b/u', $this->getWhereClause($cl), $tmpLogic);
                $this->clause->isUsed = 1;
            }

            if(! empty($logic) ){
                $query .= ' ( ' . $logic . ' ) ';
            }

            foreach($this->clause as $key => $cl){
                if( !isset($this->clause->isUsed) || !$this->clause->isUsed){
                    $query .= ' AND ' . $this->getWhereClause($cl);
                    $this->clause->isUsed = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $query;
}



private function getWhereClause($cl)
{
    return $cl->fieldId . ' = ' . $cl->value;
}
```

I have 2 problems that I need help with

1. I get a "Warning:  Attempt to assign property of non-object" on the line `$this->clause->isUsed = 1;`
2. I am trying to handle the last example "i.e. 1 AND (2 OR 3)" I get the following

   `1 AND (2 OR 3) 1 AND (2 OR name = 'Jay\'s LLC'
   ) 1 AND (2 OR 3) 1 AND (2 OR name = 'Jay\'s LLC'
   ) 1 AND (cost <> '132'
    OR 3) 1 AND (cost <> '132'
    OR name = 'Jay\'s LLC'
   ) 1 AND (cost <> '132'
    OR 3) 1 AND (cost <> '132'
    OR name = 'Jay\'s LLC'
   ) id = '1'
    AND (2 OR 3) id = '1'
    AND (2 OR name = 'Jay\'s LLC'
   ) id = '1'
    AND (2 OR 3) id = '1'
    AND (2 OR name = 'Jay\'s LLC'
   ) id = '1'
    AND (cost <> '132'
    OR 3) id = '1'
    AND (cost <> '132'
    OR name = 'Jay\'s LLC'
   ) id = '1'
    AND (cost <> '132'
    OR 3) id = '1'
    AND (cost <> '132'
    OR name = 'Jay\'s LLC'
   )`

The issue seems to be how I am trying to do a work replacement

How to correct the 2 issues that I am having?

**EDITED**

I fixed the first issue by the line changing

`$this->clause->isUsed = 1;`

to

`$this->clause[$key]->isUsed = 1;`

Comment: Are you trying to build SQL queries with this?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to build the were clause

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not using [PDO and prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)? That seems like a much simpler solution.

Comment: I am building a class that will generate a complex SQL query (multiple joins, multiple where clause) each clause have different condition (= > < <> or  LIKE) there are a lot to it than preparing the statement.

Comment: @EdHeal, it should not as I am restricted the query building to only write queries with indexes. Also, the dynamic queries will be executed on a slave to reduce the load on the master.

Comment: @MikeA - Do not think that just using an index gives good performance. Sometimes a table scan is good when partitioned (for example).

Comment: @EdHeal I have the performance considered. For the sake of question, the problem that I have today is parsing/replacing not performance :)

Comment: Your question contains errors. The third example DOES contain the 4 clause (although your example says it wouldn't), and the fourth example does not in the first mention, but later on.

Answer (score 0):

I found and fixed the problem

```
private function getAllWhereClauseStatements()
{
    $query = '';
    $totalClause = count($this->clause);

    if( $totalClause > 0 || ! empty($this->baseClientId) ){

        $query .= 'WHERE ';

        if( !empty($this->clauseLogic) ){
            $logic = $this->clauseLogic;
            $charArray = array();
            foreach($this->clause as $key => $cl){
                $charArray[] = $key;
            } 

            $charList = implode(',', $charArray);

            if( !empty($charList) ){
                $wordsCount = str_word_count($logic, 1, $charList);
            } else {
                $wordsCount = str_word_count($logic, 1);
            }

            $words = array_count_values($wordsCount);

            foreach($this->clause as $key => $cl){

                if(isset($words[$key]) && $words[$key] > 0){
                    $logic = preg_replace('/\b'.$key.'\b/u', $this->getWhereClause($cl) , $logic);
                    $this->clause[$key]->isUsed = 1;                    
                }

            }

            if(! empty($logic) ){
                $query .= ' ( ' . $logic . ' ) ';
            }

            foreach($this->clause as $key => $cl){
                if( !isset($cl->isUsed) ){
                    $query .= ' AND ' . $this->getWhereClause($cl);
                    $this->clause[$key]->isUsed = 1;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the impression  you are over complicating things a bit (leaving the question wether you should try to re-invent the wheel by writing your own query builder out of the equation, and definitely not going in to the off topic performance discussion)).

Consider the following alternative to your code (pseudo, untested!):

```
private function getWhere()
{
    // only do something if clause and logic are given
    if(empty($this->clause) || empty($this->clauseLogic) {
        return '';
    }

    // fetch the required properties so we can safely alter them
    $conditions = $this->clause;
    $logic = $this->clausLogic;

    // turn the $conditions objects into SQL strings
    array_walk($conditions, function(&$condition) {
        $condition = $condition->fieldid . '="' . $condition->value . '"';
    });

    // append missing conditions to the logic
    foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
       if (strpos($logic, $key) === false) {
          $logic .= ' AND ' . $key;
       }
    }

    // do the replacement and return
    return 'WHERE ' . strtr($logic, $conditions);
}
```

As I said, untested, but I believe it should do the same as what you are trying to achieve with your code. And you'll have to admit it reads a lot easier (and is therefore inherently easier to debug).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am all in for making my code better/cleaner. I am not sure if the logic you have will also keep the position of the parentheses and that could change the logic. I am trying to test your code, but I get this error on  `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) in` which is I think that array_walk like is not correct

Comment: Yeah, that's what you get with untested code (or at least that is what I usually get). The array_walk was not closed correctly indeed, fixed it now. Small word of advise, a descent ide would have picked up on that (and can   help you in much more ways then just that). I'm a phpstorm user myself, but there are free alternatives out there as well (like netbeans). It may take some getting used to, but it will definitly improve your development time and reduce the bugs in the long run.